# Proof that 1-Form on a Symplectic Manifold is Closed?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative

I'm trying to understand the proof of of Proposition 2.5.3 in $\textit{An Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry}$ by Marsden and Ratiu. They claim that a vector field $X$ on a symplectic, simply connected manifold $(M, \omega)$ (say ($T^*(\mathbb{R^n}), \omega)$) is Hamiltonian if and only if the Jacobian matrix of $X$ is $\omega$-skew, that is, if $DX \in \frak{sp}_n(\mathbb{R})$ (in canonical coordinates).

If we set $\theta = \iota_X(\omega)$, then $\theta$ is closed if and only if $d\iota_X(\omega) = 0$.

Now, $\mathcal{L}_X(\omega) = \iota_Xd\omega + d\iota_X(\omega)$ by Cartan's Magic Formula. Since $\omega$ is closed, $d\omega = 0$, so $\iota_Xd\omega = 0$.

Now, by another formula, $\mathcal{L}_X(\omega)(Y,Z) = X(\omega(Y,Z)) - \omega(\mathcal{L}_X(Y),Z) - \omega(Y,\mathcal{L}_X(Z))$.

I'm assuming $X(\omega(YZ)) = \iota_Xd\omega$.

In that case, $-d\iota_X(\omega) = \omega(\mathcal{L}_X(Y),Z) + \omega(Y,\mathcal{L}_X(Z))$.

I'm further assuming $\omega(\mathcal{L}_X(Y),Z) + \omega(Y,\mathcal{L}_X(Z)) = \omega(DX \cdot Y,Z) + \omega(Y, DX \cdot Z)$.

If both of these assumptions are true, then $\theta$ is closed if and only if $DX \in \frak{sp}_n(\mathbb{R})$, because $\omega(DX \cdot Y,Z) = -\omega(Y, DX \cdot Z)$ then, in which case $\theta$ is exact since $M$ is simply connected, so $\theta = \iota_X(\omega) = dH$, as desired.

Can anyone help me out with verifying/correcting the assumptions?

Comment: (Really, one only needs $H^1_{DR}(M) = 0$, not $\pi_1(M) = 1$.)

Comment: (The generalization is a little bit different from simply having $\vec{\nabla} \cdot X = 0$, as is the case with $T^*(\mathbb{R)}$  https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/1z791c/puzzle_of_the_moment_hamiltonian_vector_fields/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in local canonical coordinates, then the proof is exactly the same as the linear case, and is given in Proposition 2.5.1. I understand you're trying to come up with a "coordinate-free" proof, but the problem is that a quantity like $DX$ has no invariant meaning, and is only defined with respect to a coordinate system.

For a proof more along the lines you're attempting, imagine we have a canonical coordinate system $(z^1, \ldots, z^{2n})$ (so $\left[\omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial z^j}\right)\right] = \begin{bmatrix} 0_n & I_n \\ -I_n & 0_n\end{bmatrix}$). As you rightly say, $\mathcal{L}_X\omega = d(i_X\omega)$. However, if $X = X_H$ is a Hamiltonian vector field, then $i_{X_H}\omega = dH$, and so $\mathcal{L}_X\omega = d(dH) = 0$. If follows that
$$
X(\omega(Y,Z)) = \omega(\mathcal{L}_XY,Z) + \omega(Y,\mathcal{L}_X Z). 
$$
Now take $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$ and $Z=\frac{\partial}{\partial z^j}$. The left hand side will vanish, since the components of $\omega$ are constant in the symplectic basis. Also 
$$
\mathcal{L}_XY = \left[X,\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}\right] = -\frac{\partial X^m}{\partial z^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^m} = -(DX)_i^{\ m}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^m},
$$
and similarly for $\mathcal{L}_XZ$. This will give the result you want.